# class library referencing issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I've created a console app.  In the main project I installed Newtonsoft.Json via the Package Manager Console like this:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

I've added a "Services" project to the solution and I need to add a reference to Newtonsoft.Json.  When I right-click and go to the context menu for "Add Reference" on the "Services" project, I don't see a way to add a reference to Newtonsoft.Json.

I also tried to install the Newtonsoft.Json package like I did for the main project, but with focus on the Services project.  However, action returns the following error message in the PM console:

```
Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' already exists in project 'MyMainProject'
```

How can I get a reference to Newtonsoft.Json in my Services project?  Also, I have System.Net using statement on MyService and there is no red squiggly line which would indicate an error but HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse are not recognized in the code.  So it looks like System.Net is somehow not associated with the Services project.  Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: You need to select the Services project in the Package Manager console

Comment: Either select the Services Project in the dropdown at the top of the PM console, or add `-ProjectName Services` to the end of your command